# Getting Error after i changed my php functions

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error mentioned below:
The connection to the database is okay but some functions are not working:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\rms\rms.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rms\rms.php(408): rms->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\rms\index.php(8): rms->Is_set_up_done() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\rms\rms.php on line 31

```
function execute($data = null)
    {
        $this->statement = $this->connect->prepare($this->query);
        if($data)
        {
            $this->statement->execute($data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->statement->execute();
        }       
    }
```

```
function for_setup()
    {
        $this->query = "
        SELECT restaurant_id FROM restaurant_table
        ";

        $this->execute();

        if($this->row_count() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I wanted to make a registration page for user to register first if they have not registered!

Comment: We can't see where `$this->connect` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

$this->row_count() doesn't represent anything. If you have a list you can use $this->list->rowCount(). In addition, you can use code below for reach the values.

```
 class Deneme
{

    public $statement = '';
    public $connect;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect = new PDO(****);
    }
    function execute($data = null)
    {
        $this->statement = $this->connect->prepare($this->query);
        if ($data) {
            $this->statement->execute($data);
        } else {
            $this->statement->execute();
            $res = $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
                print_r($value);
            }
        }
    }

    function for_setup()
    {
        $this->query = "
        SELECT COUNT(*),***
        ";

        $this->execute();

        // if ($this->row_count() > 0) {
        //     return true;
        // } else {
        //     return false;
        // }
    }
}

$class = new Deneme();
$class->for_setup();
```